# Flutter http response is sometimes missing last one or two bytes

Tags: json, http, flutter, encoding, jsonexception

I have following code in my Flutter application:

```
response = await http.post(uri, body: target.parameters, headers: headers);
return SeatsMapDecoder.getFromJson(json.decode(response.body));
```

End the response for this request is something like this:

```
{"reservations":{"reserved":[439,442,443,22,23,24,25],"paid":[]},"data":{"id":1,"start_date":"25.10.2019","start_time":"20:00","price":"4.50","auditorium":{"id":1,"name":"Velika Sala","sections":[{"id":1,"auditorium_id":1,"name":"Parter I - XI","rows":[[{"id":1,"row":1,"number":1},{"id":2,"row":1,"number":2},{"id":3,"row":1,"number":3},{"id":4,"row":1,"number":4},{"id":5,"row":1,"number":5},{"id":6,"row":1,"number":6},{"id":7,"row":1,"number":7},{"id":8,"row":1,"number":8},{"id":9,"row":1,"number":9},{"id":10,"row":1,"number":10},{"id":11,"row":1,"number":11},{"id":12,"row":1,"number":12},{"id":13,"row":1,"number":13},{"id":14,"row":1,"number":14},{"id":15,"row":1,"number":15},{"id":16,"row":1,"number":16},{"id":17,"row":1,"number":17}],[{"id":18,"row":2,"number":1},{"id":19,"row":2,"number":2},{"id":20,"row":2,"number":3},{"id":21,"row":2,"number":4},{"id":22,"row":2,"number":5},{"id":23,"row":2,"number":6},{"id":24,"row":2,"number":7},{"id":25,"row":2,"number":8},{"id":26,"row":2,"number":9},{"id":27,"row":2,"number":10},{"id":28,"row":2,"number":11},{"id":29,"row":2,"number":12},{"id":30,"row":2,"number":13},{"id":31,"row":2,"number":14},{"id":32,"row":2,"number":15},{"id":33,"row":2,"number":16}],[{"id":34,"row":3,"number":1},{"id":35,"row":3,"number":2},{"id":36,"row":3,"number":3},{"id":37,"row":3,"number":4},{"id":38,"row":3,"number":5},{"id":39,"row":3,"number":6},{"id":40,"row":3,"number":7},{"id":41,"row":3,"number":8},{"id":42,"row":3,"number":9},{"id":43,"row":3,"number":10},{"id":44,"row":3,"number":11},{"id":45,"row":3,"number":12},{"id":46,"row":3,"number":13},{"id":47,"row":3,"number":14},{"id":48,"row":3,"number":15},{"id":49,"row":3,"number":16},{"id":50,"row":3,"number":17}],[{"id":51,"row":4,"number":1},{"id":52,"row":4,"number":2},{"id":53,"row":4,"number":3},{"id":54,"row":4,"number":4},{"id":55,"row":4,"number":5},{"id":56,"row":4,"number":6},{"id":57,"row":4,"number":7},{"id":58,"row":4,"number":8},{"id":59,"row":4,"number":9},{"id":60,"row":4,"number":10},{"id":61,"row":4,"number":11},{"id":62,"row":4,"number":12},{"id":63,"row":4,"number":13},{"id":64,"row":4,"number":14},{"id":65,"row":4,"number":15},{"id":66,"row":4,"number":16}],[{"id":67,"row":5,"number":1},{"id":68,"row":5,"number":2},{"id":69,"row":5,"number":3},{"id":70,"row":5,"number":4},{"id":71,"row":5,"number":5},{"id":72,"row":5,"number":6},{"id":73,"row":5,"number":7},{"id":74,"row":5,"number":8},{"id":75,"row":5,"number":9},{"id":76,"row":5,"number":10},{"id":77,"row":5,"number":11},{"id":78,"row":5,"number":12},{"id":79,"row":5,"number":13},{"id":80,"row":5,"number":14},{"id":81,"row":5,"number":15},{"id":82,"row":5,"number":16},{"id":83,"row":5,"number":17}],[{"id":84,"row":6,"number":1},{"id":85,"row":6,"number":2},{"id":86,"row":6,"number":3},{"id":87,"row":6,"number":4},{"id":88,"row":6,"number":5},{"id":89,"row":6,"number":6},{"id":90,"row":6,"number":7},{"id":91,"row":6,"number":8},{"id":92,"row":6,"number":9},{"id":93,"row":6,"number":10},{"id":94,"row":6,"number":11},{"id":95,"row":6,"number":12},{"id":96,"row":6,"number":13},{"id":97,"row":6,"number":14},{"id":98,"row":6,"number":15},{"id":99,"row":6,"number":16}],[{"id":100,"row":7,"number":1},{"id":101,"row":7,"number":2},{"id":102,"row":7,"number":3},{"id":103,"row":7,"number":4},{"id":104,"row":7,"number":5},{"id":105,"row":7,"number":6},{"id":106,"row":7,"number":7},{"id":107,"row":7,"number":8},{"id":108,"row":7,"number":9},{"id":109,"row":7,"number":10},{"id":110,"row":7,"number":11},{"id":111,"row":7,"number":12},{"id":112,"row":7,"number":13},{"id":113,"row":7,"number":14},{"id":114,"row":7,"number":15},{"id":115,"row":7,"number":16},{"id":116,"row":7,"number":17}],[{"id":117,"row":8,"number":1},{"id":118,"row":8,"number":2},{"id":119,"row":8,"number":3},{"id":120,"row":8,"number":4},{"id":121,"row":8,"number":5},{"id":122,"row":8,"number":6},{"id":123,"row":8,"number":7},{"id":124,"row":8,"number":8},{"id":125,"row":8,"number":9},{"id":126,"row":8,"number":10},{"id":127,"row":8,"number":11},{"id":128,"row":8,"number":12},{"id":129,"row":8,"number":13},{"id":130,"row":8,"number":14},{"id":131,"row":8,"number":15},{"id":132,"row":8,"number":16}],[{"id":133,"row":9,"number":1},{"id":134,"row":9,"number":2},{"id":135,"row":9,"number":3},{"id":136,"row":9,"number":4},{"id":137,"row":9,"number":5},{"id":138,"row":9,"number":6},{"id":139,"row":9,"number":7},{"id":140,"row":9,"number":8},{"id":141,"row":9,"number":9},{"id":142,"row":9,"number":10},{"id":143,"row":9,"number":11},{"id":144,"row":9,"number":12},{"id":145,"row":9,"number":13},{"id":146,"row":9,"number":14},{"id":147,"row":9,"number":15},{"id":148,"row":9,"number":16},{"id":149,"row":9,"number":17}],[{"id":150,"row":10,"number":1},{"id":151,"row":10,"number":2},{"id":152,"row":10,"number":3},{"id":153,"row":10,"number":4},{"id":154,"row":10,"number":5},{"id":155,"row":10,"number":6},{"id":156,"row":10,"number":7},{"id":157,"row":10,"number":8},{"id":158,"row":10,"number":9},{"id":159,"row":10,"number":10},{"id":160,"row":10,"number":11},{"id":161,"row":10,"number":12},{"id":162,"row":10,"number":13},{"id":163,"row":10,"number":14},{"id":164,"row":10,"number":15},{"id":165,"row":10,"number":16}],[{"id":166,"row":11,"number":1},{"id":167,"row":11,"number":2},{"id":168,"row":11,"number":3},{"id":169,"row":11,"number":4},{"id":170,"row":11,"number":5},{"id":171,"row":11,"number":6},{"id":172,"row":11,"number":7},{"id":173,"row":11,"number":8},{"id":174,"row":11,"number":9},{"id":175,"row":11,"number":10},{"id":176,"row":11,"number":11},{"id":177,"row":11,"number":12},{"id":178,"row":11,"number":13},{"id":179,"row":11,"number":14},{"id":180,"row":11,"number":15},{"id":181,"row":11,"number":16},{"id":182,"row":11,"number":17}]]},{"id":2,"auditorium_id":1,"name":"Parter XII - XXIII","rows":[[{"id":183,"row":12,"number":1},{"id":184,"row":12,"number":2},{"id":185,"row":12,"number":3},{"id":186,"row":12,"number":4},{"id":187,"row":12,"number":5},{"id":188,"row":12,"number":6},{"id":189,"row":12,"number":7},{"id":190,"row":12,"number":8},{"id":191,"row":12,"number":9},{"id":192,"row":12,"number":10},{"id":193,"row":12,"number":11},{"id":194,"row":12,"number":12},{"id":195,"row":12,"number":13},{"id":196,"row":12,"number":14},{"id":197,"row":12,"number":15},{"id":198,"row":12,"number":16},{"id":199,"row":12,"number":17}],[{"id":200,"row":13,"number":1},{"id":201,"row":13,"number":2},{"id":202,"row":13,"number":3},{"id":203,"row":13,"number":4},{"id":204,"row":13,"number":5},{"id":205,"row":13,"number":6},{"id":206,"row":13,"number":7},{"id":207,"row":13,"number":8},{"id":208,"row":13,"number":9},{"id":209,"row":13,"number":10},{"id":210,"row":13,"number":11},{"id":211,"row":13,"number":12},{"id":212,"row":13,"number":13},{"id":213,"row":13,"number":14},{"id":214,"row":13,"number":15},{"id":215,"row":13,"number":16}],[{"id":216,"row":14,"number":1},{"id":217,"row":14,"number":2},{"id":218,"row":14,"number":3},{"id":219,"row":14,"number":4},{"id":220,"row":14,"number":5},{"id":221,"row":14,"number":6},{"id":222,"row":14,"number":7},{"id":223,"row":14,"number":8},{"id":224,"row":14,"number":9},{"id":225,"row":14,"number":10},{"id":226,"row":14,"number":11},{"id":227,"row":14,"number":12},{"id":228,"row":14,"number":13},{"id":229,"row":14,"number":14},{"id":230,"row":14,"number":15},{"id":231,"row":14,"number":16},{"id":232,"row":14,"number":17}],[{"id":233,"row":15,"number":1},{"id":234,"row":15,"number":2},{"id":235,"row":15,"number":3},{"id":236,"row":15,"number":4},{"id":237,"row":15,"number":5},{"id":238,"row":15,"number":6},{"id":239,"row":15,"number":7},{"id":240,"row":15,"number":8},{"id":241,"row":15,"number":9},{"id":242,"row":15,"number":10},{"id":243,"row":15,"number":11},{"id":244,"row":15,"number":12},{"id":245,"row":15,"number":13},{"id":246,"row":15,"number":14},{"id":247,"row":15,"number":15},{"id":248,"row":15,"number":16}],[{"id":249,"row":16,"number":1},{"id":250,"row":16,"number":2},{"id":251,"row":16,"number":3},{"id":252,"row":16,"number":4},{"id":253,"row":16,"number":5},{"id":254,"row":16,"number":6},{"id":255,"row":16,"number":7},{"id":256,"row":16,"number":8},{"id":257,"row":16,"number":9},{"id":258,"row":16,"number":10},{"id":259,"row":16,"number":11},{"id":260,"row":16,"number":12},{"id":261,"row":16,"number":13},{"id":262,"row":16,"number":14},{"id":263,"row":16,"number":15},{"id":264,"row":16,"number":16},{"id":265,"row":16,"number":17}],[{"id":266,"row":17,"number":1},{"id":267,"row":17,"number":2},{"id":268,"row":17,"number":3},{"id":269,"row":17,"number":4},{"id":270,"row":17,"number":5},{"id":271,"row":17,"number":6},{"id":272,"row":17,"number":7},{"id":273,"row":17,"number":8},{"id":274,"row":17,"number":9},{"id":275,"row":17,"number":10},{"id":276,"row":17,"number":11},{"id":277,"row":17,"number":12},{"id":278,"row":17,"number":13},{"id":279,"row":17,"number":14},{"id":280,"row":17,"number":15},{"id":281,"row":17,"number":16}],[{"id":282,"row":18,"number":1},{"id":283,"row":18,"number":2},{"id":284,"row":18,"number":3},{"id":285,"row":18,"number":4},{"id":286,"row":18,"number":5},{"id":287,"row":18,"number":6},{"id":288,"row":18,"number":7},{"id":289,"row":18,"number":8},{"id":290,"row":18,"number":9},{"id":291,"row":18,"number":10},{"id":292,"row":18,"number":11},{"id":293,"row":18,"number":12},{"id":294,"row":18,"number":13},{"id":295,"row":18,"number":14},{"id":296,"row":18,"number":15},{"id":297,"row":18,"number":16},{"id":298,"row":18,"number":17}],[{"id":299,"row":19,"number":1},{"id":300,"row":19,"number":2},{"id":301,"row":19,"number":3},{"id":302,"row":19,"number":4},{"id":303,"row":19,"number":5},{"id":304,"row":19,"number":6},{"id":305,"row":19,"number":7},{"id":306,"row":19,"number":8},{"id":307,"row":19,"number":9},{"id":308,"row":19,"number":10},{"id":309,"row":19,"number":11},{"id":310,"row":19,"number":12},{"id":311,"row":19,"number":13},{"id":312,"row":19,"number":14},{"id":313,"row":19,"number":15},{"id":314,"row":19,"number":16}],[{"id":315,"row":20,"number":1},{"id":316,"row":20,"number":2},{"id":317,"row":20,"number":3},{"id":318,"row":20,"number":4},{"id":319,"row":20,"number":5},{"id":320,"row":20,"number":6},{"id":321,"row":20,"number":7},{"id":322,"row":20,"number":8},{"id":323,"row":20,"number":9},{"id":324,"row":20,"number":10},{"id":325,"row":20,"number":11},{"id":326,"row":20,"number":12},{"id":327,"row":20,"number":13},{"id":328,"row":20,"number":14},{"id":329,"row":20,"number":15},{"id":330,"row":20,"number":16},{"id":331,"row":20,"number":17}],[{"id":332,"row":21,"number":1},{"id":333,"row":21,"number":2},{"id":334,"row":21,"number":3},{"id":335,"row":21,"number":4},{"id":336,"row":21,"number":5},{"id":337,"row":21,"number":6},{"id":338,"row":21,"number":7},{"id":339,"row":21,"number":8},{"id":340,"row":21,"number":9},{"id":341,"row":21,"number":10},{"id":342,"row":21,"number":11},{"id":343,"row":21,"number":12},{"id":344,"row":21,"number":13},{"id":345,"row":21,"number":14},{"id":346,"row":21,"number":15},{"id":347,"row":21,"number":16}],[{"id":348,"row":22,"number":1},{"id":349,"row":22,"number":2},{"id":350,"row":22,"number":3},{"id":351,"row":22,"number":4},{"id":352,"row":22,"number":5},{"id":353,"row":22,"number":6},{"id":354,"row":22,"number":7},{"id":355,"row":22,"number":8},{"id":356,"row":22,"number":9},{"id":357,"row":22,"number":10},{"id":358,"row":22,"number":11},{"id":359,"row":22,"number":12},{"id":360,"row":22,"number":13},{"id":361,"row":22,"number":14},{"id":362,"row":22,"number":15},{"id":363,"row":22,"number":16},{"id":364,"row":22,"number":17}],[{"id":365,"row":23,"number":1},{"id":366,"row":23,"number":2},{"id":367,"row":23,"number":3},{"id":368,"row":23,"number":4},{"id":369,"row":23,"number":5},{"id":370,"row":23,"number":6},{"id":371,"row":23,"number":7},{"id":372,"row":23,"number":8},{"id":373,"row":23,"number":9},{"id":374,"row":23,"number":10},{"id":375,"row":23,"number":11},{"id":376,"row":23,"number":12},{"id":377,"row":23,"number":13},{"id":378,"row":23,"number":14},{"id":379,"row":23,"number":15},{"id":380,"row":23,"number":16}]]},{"id":3,"auditorium_id":1,"name":"Balkon","rows":[[{"id":381,"row":1,"number":1},{"id":382,"row":1,"number":2},{"id":383,"row":1,"number":3},{"id":384,"row":1,"number":4},{"id":385,"row":1,"number":5},{"id":386,"row":1,"number":6},{"id":387,"row":1,"number":7},{"id":388,"row":1,"number":8},{"id":389,"row":1,"number":9},{"id":390,"row":1,"number":10},{"id":391,"row":1,"number":11}],[{"id":392,"row":2,"number":1},{"id":393,"row":2,"number":2},{"id":394,"row":2,"number":3},{"id":395,"row":2,"number":4},{"id":396,"row":2,"number":5},{"id":397,"row":2,"number":6},{"id":398,"row":2,"number":7},{"id":399,"row":2,"number":8},{"id":400,"row":2,"number":9},{"id":401,"row":2,"number":10}],[{"id":402,"row":3,"number":1},{"id":403,"row":3,"number":2},{"id":404,"row":3,"number":3},{"id":405,"row":3,"number":4},{"id":406,"row":3,"number":5},{"id":407,"row":3,"number":6},{"id":408,"row":3,"number":7},{"id":409,"row":3,"number":8},{"id":410,"row":3,"number":9},{"id":411,"row":3,"number":10},{"id":412,"row":3,"number":11}],[{"id":413,"row":4,"number":1},{"id":414,"row":4,"number":2},{"id":415,"row":4,"number":3},{"id":416,"row":4,"number":4},{"id":417,"row":4,"number":5},{"id":418,"row":4,"number":6},{"id":419,"row":4,"number":7},{"id":420,"row":4,"number":8},{"id":421,"row":4,"number":9},{"id":422,"row":4,"number":10}],[{"id":423,"row":5,"number":1},{"id":424,"row":5,"number":2},{"id":425,"row":5,"number":3},{"id":426,"row":5,"number":4},{"id":427,"row":5,"number":5},{"id":428,"row":5,"number":6},{"id":429,"row":5,"number":7},{"id":430,"row":5,"number":8},{"id":431,"row":5,"number":9},{"id":432,"row":5,"number":10}],[{"id":433,"row":6,"number":1},{"id":434,"row":6,"number":2},{"id":435,"row":6,"number":3},{"id":436,"row":6,"number":4},{"id":437,"row":6,"number":5},{"id":438,"row":6,"number":6}],[{"id":439,"row":7,"number":1},{"id":440,"row":7,"number":2},{"id":441,"row":7,"number":3},{"id":442,"row":7,"number":4},{"id":443,"row":7,"number":5},{"id":444,"row":7,"number":6}]]}],"seats_map":"main"}}}
```

On the server side I only do this (Laravel 6):

```
$seatsMap = $service->getSeatsMap();
return response()->json($seatsMap);
```

However sometimes while working on the application, I got json format exception.

```
FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 14076)...,"row":7,"number":5},{"id":444,"row":7,"number":6}]]}],"seats_m
```

Debuging showed me that sometimes last bracket `}` in the `response.body` is missing. And the length of the body is sometimes 14076 bytes and sometimes 14075 bytes. It's like flutter's http library forgets to read last byte.

Also I tried returning this on server side:

```
return response()->json($data, 200, [
            "Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        ]);
```

but still sometimes it happens that last `}` is missing in the `response.body` property.

What could be the cause of this error? I doubt it's server side since I use Laravel to json encode associative array.

**EDIT**

Looks like this is only happening on emulator, on my Huawei Mate 10 PRO, i cannot reproduce this bug...

**EDIT 2**

Also this stopped happening on emulator once I pushed backend code to server and now I am retrieving data from server

Comment: i had this problem with a library called Fuel (kotlin library) in android native development. i hate it to see this happen in flutter

Comment: What kind of headers do you use? I don't remember exactly, I had some bugs, it was solved, when I started to use 
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

Comment: @awaik Content-Type is just set to "application/json", I tried yours but i still have error

Comment: Same problem for me using Volley library in native android code, only with emulator... Seems to come from emulator.