# Flutter: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character XXXXXX)

Tags: json, flutter

##### Problem Description

When decoding a JSON in Flutter, I receive an error stating that a character is missing, such as quotes ("), colons (:), commas (,), or the last character (curly or square brackets). This happens randomly and usually near the end of the JSON.

##### When does the problem occur?

Starting from a JSON with 100 KB, the issues begin to occur. With JSONs larger than 300 KB, it's almost certain that the error will occur. With JSONs smaller than 100 KB, it usually doesn't happen, but it still can.

##### Additional Information

The API was built in Laravel and has been tested with Postman, returning the expected values correctly and without errors.

##### Http class

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    
    class Http {
      Http._internal();
      static final Http _instance = Http._internal();
      Map<String, String> headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      };
      String baseUrl = 'http://ipv4/api';
    
      factory Http() {
        return _instance;
      }
    
      Future<http.Response> get(
        String path, {
        Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters,
        Map<String, String>? customHeaders,
      }) async {
        final Uri uri =
            Uri.parse('$baseUrl$path').replace(queryParameters: queryParameters);
    
        final response = await http.get(
          uri,
          headers: {...headers, ...?customHeaders},
        );
    
        return response;
      }
    }
```

##### Code

```
    final token = await _tokenFuture;
    final response = await Http().get('/construction', customHeaders: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'});
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> jsonList = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(json.decode(response.body));
```

##### Some solutions already tried

- Using Dio or Http: both had the same results
- Using http or https
- Adding ResponseType.plain
- Regex to handle received data

##### Error examples

- Missing quotes in the key: ...material":"15000","labor:"10000"...
- Missing quotes in the value: ...material":"15000","labor":10000"...
- Missing comma: ...material":"15000""labor":"10000"...
- Missing colon: ...material""15000","labor":"10000"...
- Missing closing brackets (not verified if it can be missing in the middle)

##### Edit

- Duplicated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59326945/flutter-http-response-is-sometimes-missing-last-one-or-two-bytes)
- Any character can be missing in response.body
- The error only occurs on the emulator

Comment: What happens when you print the length of the emitted JSON at the server, and compare with the length received in the client (of .body and .bodyBytes)? Can you reproduce in a standalone Dart program? Can you duplicate using HTTP, capture with wireshark, and see if the lengths match, whether there are missing chars.

Comment: Server: 771044
Client: 771027 to 771043

Comment: Can you share an example of the json that is giving troubles?

Comment: Try testing in a standalone Dart program.

Answer (score 0):

i was suffering with a similar error but with the Dio library. In my case the root cause was always a missing character in the end of the data, with that in mind i got it working with the following:

first i changed the response type from

```
responseType: ResponseType.json
```

to

```
responseType: ResponseType.plain
```

i did this so that the FormatException didn't come from the library itself.

Then i just concatenated the missing curly bracket on the response with the following:

```
  final response = await request();

  dynamic formattedResponse;

  try {
    formattedResponse = jsonDecode(response.data);
  } on FormatException {
    log('Got format exception, trying to format response...');
    //Concatenating the "}"
    formattedResponse = jsonDecode('${response.data}}');

    if (formattedResponse == null) {
      rethrow;
    } else {
      log('Response formatted successfully!');
    }
  }
```

im not proud of this solution but it got my system running flawlessly again, so i hope it helps!

By the way in my research i've found this [issue](https://github.com/cfug/dio/issues/1930) from 2023 that was extremely similar to my problem, but with no viable solution.